# QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username'

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

My code:
values aren't updated in database and get this error:

> (Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'
>   (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `username` =
>   anikatabassum) ) and ( "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054
>   Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as
>   aggregate from `users` where `username` = anikatabassum)`enter code
>   here`)

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: If that's what it says it must be true. Please check your table in the DB and that you are connected to the DB you think you are. I would personally be wary of using the keyword aggregate - this should not cause a problem but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the database , if the table contain `username` column or not , if the table not contain it , please run this command : `php artisan migrate:fresh`

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `php artisan migrate:fresh`